# JSON.serialize not returning valid json for nested objects

Tags: json, salesforce, apex

I need to serialize a nested structure of Salesforce objects as JSON but the result doesn't parse correctly.

```
public class Checklist_JSON {
// class to represent the structure of the checklist 
//   one opportunity
//   one account
//   one finance checklist (custom object)
//   one/more integration checklists, (custom objects) each with
//   one/more campaigns (custom objects)
public opportunity this_opp{get;set;}
public account this_acc{get;set;}
public finance_checklist__c this_fin{get;set;}
public map <integration_checklist__c, list<ph_campaign__c>> ints_cams{get;set;}
}
```

I then simply `JSON.serialize(this_checklist_json);`

The result can be parsed correctly for all objects except the integration_checklist__c - i.e. the keyset of the ints_cams map.

The other objects (account/oppty/etc.) each have a node 'attributes' containing the correctly formatted name/value pairs e.g.
    `{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Account/0015E00000WDO8ZQAX"},"Id":"0015E00000WDO8ZQAX",
etc.`

but the integration_checklist__c doesn't have an 'attributes' node and has the fields represented like:
`{"Integration_Checklist__c:{Id=a1E5E00000088lNUAQ, Name=INT-000339,
etc.`

i.e. without quote marks around "ID":"a1E5E00000088lNUAQ"

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well... and what would you imagine the result should be? How would you represent "map whose keys are also objects" in a simple javascript object (because your map keys would be translated to field names during serialisation)?

Pick a primitive as the map key (Id, Decimal, String) or worst case - serialise the keys to strings, build new Map> and serialise that?

SF tries here, it calls "toString()" on your sobjects used keys, that's why you see 1 giant string. It looks identical to results of System.debug() call, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @eyescream for taking the time to respond.

The fundamental problem was that I shouldn't have been trying to represent the parent-child relationship as a map.

I've re-written based on represnting that relationship as a class:

```
public class Checklist_JSON {
    // class to represent the structure of the checklist 
    //   one opportunity
    //   one account
    //   one finance checklist
    //   one/more integration checklists, each with
    //   one/more campaigns
    public opportunity this_opp{get;set;}
    public account this_acc{get;set;}
    public finance_checklist__c this_fin{get;set;}
    public list<int_cams> these_ints_cams {get;set;}
}

public class int_cams {
    //class to represent parent-children relationship int-list<cams>
    public integration_checklist__c this_int {get;set;}
    public list <ph_campaign__c> these_cams {get;set;}
}
```

serializing the result now produces my intended json output.